# Как сверстать такой заголовок?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите, как сверстать такой заголовок, с двум линиями с боку, только чтоб линии при уменьшении экрана не уплывали.

```
<div class="header__offer-title">JUST FOR YOU ON THEMEFOREST</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте before и after. И в целом можете открыть консоль и посмотреть как сделано.

Comment: Через псевдоэлементы я знаю как делать, я не знаю как сделать, чтоб полоски уменьшались при сужении без медиазапросов, а через консоль не выйдет, так как этот заголовок взят с PSD макета

Comment: ставьте width 100% для них, чтобы ограничить max-width: 100px и всё.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать красивый заголовок в листе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846877/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Используй :before, :after

```css
.header__offer-title {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
}

.header__offer-title:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header__offer-title:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__offer-title">JUST FOR YOU ON THEMEFOREST</div>
```